# getnameinfo() from ifaddrs.h gives junk values in C

Tags: c, network-programming

I want to retrieve ip address of the current wireless interface I use. For that I use `getnameinfo()` function from [ifaddrs.h](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) library. My problem is that this function return junk values rather than the actual ip address.

Here is the function I use:

```
void getWIFromSystem(WI **WIHead) {
  struct ifaddrs *ifaddr, *ifa;
  char host[NI_MAXHOST];

  if (getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == -1) {
    perror("getifaddrs");
    exit(-1);
  }

  /* Walk through linked list, maintaining head pointer so we
     can free list later */
  for (ifa = ifaddr; ifa != NULL; ifa = ifa->ifa_next) {
    if (ifa->ifa_addr == NULL || ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family != AF_PACKET) {
      continue;
    }

    if (check_wireless(ifa->ifa_name)) { / /we want only wireless interfaces
      //getWIAdress(ifa->ifa_name, host);
      getnameinfo(ifa->ifa_addr, (ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) ? sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) : sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6), host, NI_MAXHOST, NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);
      addWI(&WIHead, ifa->ifa_name, host);
    }
  }

  freeifaddrs(ifaddr);
}
```

I manage to solve the problem with another function I created but I can't understand why I get junk values using the `getnameinfo()`

My other function that solves the problem:

```
void getWIAdress(char *name, char *host) {
   int fd;
   struct ifreq ifr;

   fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

   /* I want to get an IPv4 IP address */
   ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;

   /* I want IP address attached to specified name */
   strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, name, IFNAMSIZ-1);

   ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr);

   close(fd);

   /* copy result */
   strcpy(host, inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr)->sin_addr));
}
```

Screenshot of the junk values:

[image]

Comment: The first `if` ensures that `sa_family` is always `AF_PACKET`. So why are you testing it against `AF_INET` when calling `getnameinfo()`? I think you need to check the error code returned.

Comment: @Barmar you mean from `getnameinfo`? Yes it gives negative values. Hmm how can I fix it?

Comment: Yes. `getnameinfo` returns `0` if it's successful, or an error code if it's not. The man page lists all the error codes.

Comment: @Barmar okay fix it. I'll upload a solution right now.

Comment: Please do not post a screenshot of your output. it is just plain text and no graphical artwork.

Comment: @Gerhardh I did it to show what I mean with the phrase "junk values".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in this condition:

```
if (ifa->ifa_addr == NULL || ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family != AF_PACKET)
```

We have to change `AF_PACKET` with `AF_INET`. This will also allow us to bypass virtual interfaces generated by `airmon-ng` from `aircrack-ng` package.

With the above fix we also don't have to check for `AF_INET` in `getnameinfo()` as we stick to IPv4 adresses.

```
getnameinfo(ifa->ifa_addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in), host, NI_MAXHOST, NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);
```